# Replacing hashtag with links, it only replaces last word in the string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a hashtag system, so I reached the edit text feature where I want to replace the entered edit with hashtag links if the user type hashtag words. So I am using JavaScript and jQuery to do this but the problem is that the for loop is only replacing the last word in the string and not all the string with a links.

```
// Turn hashtags into links
var discussionText = "#example #text #string #one #two #three #hashtag #word";
var wordsArray = discussionText.split(" ");

for (i = 0; i < wordsArray.length; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  if (wordsArray[i].indexOf('#') > -1) {
    var wordWithoutHashtag = wordsArray[i].replace("#", "");
    console.log(wordWithoutHashtag);
    $("#" + editDiscussionButtonId + "-" + editDiscussionButtonUserId + "-spanDiscussionEdit").html(function() {
      return $(this).text().replace(wordsArray[i], "<a href='search.php?sec=all&q=" + wordWithoutHashtag + "' class='hashtag_link'>" + wordsArray[i] + "</a>");
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the [`html(function)`](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) to use the existing html argument. When you use `text()` it doesn't return the previous  `<a>` you created in previous iterations of the loop, only the text inside the `<a>`.

```
$(selector).html(function(index, existingHtml){
   return existingHtml.replace(wordsArray[i], ....
});
```

Similarly if you just changed `$(this).text().replace..` to `$(this).html().replace...` it would work.

---

A more efficient approach would be the get the existing content once before the loop and do all the modifications to the string stored in variable, then replace the modified content once after the loop completes

Comment: thanks for your answer well i tried it, it works but it doesnt work for #face and #facebook for example because it will replace #facebook with a link to #face so i was trying to come up with a solution and i made one which works perfectly after posting this question i was thinking in the same way for a solution i will post it

Answer (score 1):

After i posted this question, i continue trying with solutions until i came up with the below which works perfectly for all cases tags

```
var discussionText = "#example #text #string #one #two #three #hashtag #word";
var wordsArray = discussionText.split(" ");
                    var fullText = "";

                    for(i=0; i < wordsArray.length; i++) {

                        if (wordsArray[i].indexOf('#') > -1) {
                            var wordWithoutHashtag = wordsArray[i].replace("#", "");

                            var wordLink = wordsArray[i].replace(wordsArray[i], "<a href='search.php?sec=all&q="+wordWithoutHashtag+"' class='hashtag_link'>"+wordsArray[i]+"</a>");
                            fullText += " " + wordLink;
                            $("#"+editDiscussionButtonId+"-"+editDiscussionButtonUserId+"-spanDiscussionEdit").html(fullText);
                        } else {
                            fullText += " "+wordsArray[i];
                        }

                    }
```